# Reduce vertical space between heading and body

Tags: letters, lettre

I use the [lettre](https://ctan.org/pkg/lettre) package to write letters (in French).

This package generates a massive space between the heading and the subject line.

See:

[image]

This space is created to print references of the letter but I never want to print reference number in a letter.

**How can I reduce this vertical space?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{to Mr X}
\name{sender}
\conc{Subject}

\opening{Dear sir,}

\kant[42]

\closing{Bye Bye}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would adding to your preamble `\setlength{\openingspace}{0cm}` be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header of the `letter` environment is built in the [**p**icture-mode **i**s **c**urrently **t**he **u**ser **r**ecommended **e**nterprise **m**ethod **o**f **d**rawing **e**asily](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45267628#45267628) (picture-mode).

This picture takes as height the contents of `\pict@let@height`, and as starting vertical position, `\pict@let@voffset`. These parameters are set internally by `lettre.cls` as:

```
\def\pict@let@height{65}%
\def\pict@let@voffset{0}%
```

reducing only `\pict@let@height` makes the contents of the header to be inserted off the top of the page. Apparently the sum `\pict@let@height+\pict@let@voffset` must equal `65`.

So one can define a macro:

```
\def\SetHeaderSize#1{%
  \edef\pict@let@height{#1}%
  \edef\pict@let@voffset{\numexpr65-#1}%
}
```

that takes as argument the desired height of the header and it computes the `voffset` automatically (the macro has to be used right after `\begin{letter}`). I used `15` and it looked okay for me:

> [image]

Unfortunately I don't think there's a *more automatic* way to do this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\SetHeaderSize#1{%
  \edef\pict@let@height{#1}%
  \edef\pict@let@voffset{\numexpr65-#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{to Mr X}

\SetHeaderSize{15}

\name{sender}
\conc{Subject}

\opening{Dear sir,}

\kant[42]

\closing{Bye Bye}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```